# Analysing time complexity when input is doubling for merge sort

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

I'm trying to theoretically understand how much longer it would take when the input size passed to merge sort is doubled. I was a reading a textbook which stated that:

"Since the runtime for mergesort (for large N) is O(N log_2 N), we should consider the ratio, r = N^{1.1} log_2(N^{1.1})/(N log_2(N)). This simplifies to 1.1 N^{0.1} which is around 3.5"

I wanted to asked how they computed that it would take roughly 3.5 times longer for merge sort to execute when input size is doubled. Essentially, how they want about that transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Using logarithm arithmetic:

[image: a]

which still depends on N.

My guess is that they assumed that a large number for N is 100000 so:

[image: a]

Comment: yep I understand the logarithm arithmetic but don't understand how the textbook got it to that form in the first place

Comment: They examined an input which is larger than the original input by a power of 1.1. For an input the size I guessed, it would be about 3 times larger.